# Learning how to use Mapinfo Professional ?

Tags: mapinfo, references

I am wondering if there is a good website where can I learn how to use Map Info Professional ? I am an advanced ArcGIS user and am a beginner MapInfo. Thanks.

What I mean "Good website" I mean they  can be from site where they give you the steps, documents, powerpoint, pdf related to MapInfo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pitney Bowes has some web-based training videos online that are pretty comprehensive:

http://tutorials.mapinfo.com/tutorials/Index.htm

They walk you through a lot of the basic functionality, but don't cover too much of the advanced features. The training includes some sample data and exercises.

Answer (score 0):

PBBI themselves have a pretty good resource center in regards to videos. It can be found here http://www.pbinsight.com/support/education/video-tutorials/product/mapinfo-professional/